# Only get street and country from Libpostal (Pypostal) - PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm using `libpostal` - `pypostal` to parse an address but I only need the `road` and the `country` in an Array `["franklin ave","usa"],["leonard st","united kingdom"]`

How can I achieve this ?

Return type is `net.razorvine.pickle.objects.classdictconstructor`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

LIBPOSTAL_LOADED = False
@udf("string")
def parse(address):
   from postal.parser import parse_address

   address_parsed = parse_address(address)

   return str(address_parsed)

spark.createDataFrame(['781 Franklin Ave Crown Heights Brooklyn NYC NY 11216 USA','The Book Club 100-106 Leonard St, Shoreditch, London, Greater London, EC2A 4RH, United Kingdom'], "string").toDF("address").select(parse("address")).show(truncate=False)
```

[image: 1]

**@MCK Updated on request**

```
@udf("array<string>")
def parse(address):
   from postal.parser import parse_address

   address_parsed = [a[0] for a in parse_address(address) if a[1] in ['road', 'country']]

   return address_parsed

+------------------+
|[franklin ave,usa]|
+------------------+
```

This is as expected
############################################################################

```
@udf("array<string>")
def parse(address):
   from postal.parser import parse_address

   address_parsed = [a[0] for a in parse_address(address) if a[1] in ['road', 'country']]

   return address_parsed[0]

+-----+
|null |
+-----+
```

This is not as expected. I expect first element from `address_parsed` that is `franklin ave`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try a list comprehension before returning the parsed address:

```
@udf("array<string>")
def parse(address):
   from postal.parser import parse_address

   address_parsed = [a[0] for a in parse_address(address) if a[1] in ['road', 'country']]

   return address_parsed
```

Comment: I've an additional question. It returns a list of strings but I cant access the items from the list e.g. `address_parsed[0]` for road

Comment: Maybe address_parsed is None/null?

Comment: It’s not None/Null.  It contains the road and country but ‘address_parsed[0]’ returns Null. It looks like it’s a string separated by a comma instead of list items. There are no quotes.

Comment: Oh, that's because the signature of the udf is `array<string>`, so you need to change that to `string` if you want to return a string only.

Comment: I need a array<string>. It returns an array but with a single string (road and country separated by a comma) but not as list items and thats the issue. I’d like to use the separate list items. For example road = address_parsed[0]

Comment: Updated my question. Current output: `[franklin ave,usa],[leonard st,united kingdom]` instead of `["franklin ave","usa"],["leonard st","united kingdom"]`

Comment: I think that should be an array of strings. Spark `df.show()` does not include double quotes when it shows an array of strings. You can check the schema `df.printSchema()` to confirm whether the column is indeed an array of strings. I believe it is.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity or my lack of knowledge. I want to add some extras in the UDF. If I understand correctly, the list comprehension gives a list of items. I would expect `address_parsed [0]` to give me the values of `road`, but it doesn't. I don't think it would be useful to perform `address_parsed = [a [0] for a in parse_address (address) if a [1] in ['road']]` and once `address_parsed = [a [0] for a in parse_address (address) if a [1] in ['country']] `. I am not talking about the final DataFrame but still within the UDF.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It'll be helpful if you show the complete UDF that you have tried, and the output that you've got...

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the different UDF that you tried,  and  the corresponding output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230176/discussion-between-mck-and-john-doe).

Comment: Could you try `address_parsed = [a[0] for a in parse_address(address) if a[1] in ['road']]` and `return address_parsed`? You got null because you're returning `"franklin ave"` instead of `["franklin ave"]`.

Comment: you need to return `[address_parsed[0]]` if you want `array<string>`

Comment: if you return `address_parsed[0]`, you need to have `string` as return type.